# Request forwarding

Tags: dns, forwarding, tomato, dnsmasq

I have a WRT54G router running with a sub-domain pointed to it, e.g.: sub.domain.com. Now I want to forward external requests (but also local) to computers which are connected to my router so if I request externally:

```
bob.sub.domain.com to 192.168.1.3
fred.sub.domain.com to 192.168.1.4
```

I've tried the following in the DNSMasq config:

```
address=/bob.sub.domain.com/192.168.1.4
```

But it references to the computer which is port forwarded if i request it externally. If I request it internally it obviously works just fine :P

How should I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you should consider setting up something like a Reverse Proxy instead. I'm not that familiar with WRTs, so I don't know if you can do that within the router itself, or if you'd need to route everything to a machine that does it for you. "Pound" is a reasonably simple reverse proxy service you could set up.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Just installed DD-WRT and now installing a reverse proxy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of thing can be managed by a reverse proxy (as we've discussed in the comments).

mark_dj has reported that [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) has a reverse proxy component you can install on it and is using that to solve his particular problem. (Or were you saying that you're setting up a reverse proxy on a separate machine and forwarding all requests?).

I've posted this answer for future viewers of this question.